# Licença free Contruct 2

Tags: android, ios, engine

Pesquisando li que o Construct 2 tem uma limitação de receita na versão *free* você não pode obter lucro nenhum com o jogo, mas quando eles dizem isso quer dizer que o jogo não pode gerar receita nem por propaganda?

Comment: Você vai obter lucro com as ads, então não pode. :)